# javascript case switch according to div data

Tags: javascript

**hello **

1) i want the case to switch according to what is showing in the div " display".

- the div display is showing the number of clicks on the button add.

2) also if its possible to add a case if the number more than 4 show xxxx.

3) can i display image instead of text in the case ?

- here is my code but its not working.

```js
$('[id=display]').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  text = $.trim(text);

  switch (text) {
    case '1':
      $('#final').text('x---');
      break;
    case '2':
      $('#final').text('xx--');
      break;
    case '3':
      $('#final').text('xxx-');
      break;
    case '4':
      $('#final').text('xxxx');
      break;
    default:
      $('#final').text('----');
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var capnum = 0;

  function add() {
    capnum++;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = capnum;
  }
</script>

<button onclick="add()">add</button>

<div id="display">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(capnum);
  </script>
</div>

<div id="final"></div>
```

Comment: is something supposed to change when you click the "add" button? Because your `each` function only runs once since it's not inside the `add` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need update upon every click event. See code below.

```
<script>
var capnum = 0;
function add() {
    capnum++;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = capnum;
    update();
}
</script>

<script>
    function update() {
        $('[id=display]').each(function () {
            var text = $(this).text();
            text = $.trim(text);
            // discard switch statement for better (from dandavis's comment)
            $('#final').text({1:'x---',2: 'xx--',3:'xxx-', ... }[text] || '----'); 
        });
    }
</script>
```

Question 3: sure.

Comment: `$('#final').text({1:'x---',2: 'xx--',3:'xxx-', ... }[text1] || '----');`

Comment: i tried in the fiddle its not working , can you try ?
https://jsfiddle.net/musanajame/6u6kd6d6/1/